# Two sortables stacked using z-index

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have this setup. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andreiglingeanu/acnvzvbj/2/) link.

```js
$('.item').draggable({
 helper: 'clone',
 connectToSortable: '.first-sortable, .second-sortable',
});

$('.first-sortable').sortable({
 connectWith: '.second-sortable',
  receive: function () {
    $('.logger1').addClass('animated');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.logger1').removeClass('animated');
    }, 300);
  }
});

$('.second-sortable').sortable({
  connectWith: '.first-sortable',
    receive: function () {
      $('.logger2').addClass('animated');
      setTimeout(function () {
          $('.logger2').removeClass('animated');
      }, 300);
    }
});
```

```css
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.first-sortable {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.second-sortable {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(3, 3, 3, .8);
  z-index: 10;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.logger2,
.logger1 {
  transition: all .3s color;
}

.animated {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="first-sortable"></div>
  <div class="second-sortable"></div>
</div>


<div class="item"></div>

<div class="logger1">Blue Sortable Receive</div>
<div class="logger2">Dark Sortable Receive</div>
```

The main idea is that, as you can see, is that the dark sortable is above the first one, it is positioned using `position: absolute` and `z-index`. I have a little bit of opacity for the black one, just so I can look what happens with the first sortable.

Below the bottom red square we have two indicators that shows when [receive](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) event is fired on the specific sortable.

Please note the fact that when you drop an item onto the blue sortable, only indicator for this sortable is fired. When I drop a new item onto the black a receive event is fired on both sortables.

Is this behavior a desired one? I think, in this case just the dark one have to receive this event.

I wonder if this is not jQuery UI bug. [Ticket](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/14913).

Comment: put the dark thingy actually inside the blue thingy and it works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/acnvzvbj/3/ why must you want to position it outside in DOM..?

Comment: @TJ In fact, I have an interface like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/andreiglingeanu/Lt5r234t/), where I have two sortable below the dark one. Here's the real gotcha. Do you know about some workaround for this use case?

Comment: Nest the sortables are adjust their appearance as you wish using CSS..?

Comment: The one to which you're gonna give lowest z-index should be the outer most, and the one with highest z index should be innermost, in DOM